# Firebase data fetch returns meaningless data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wrote a code to fetch data from Firebase db. My Firebase db structure looks like this:

[image]

I wrote a js code below in my.html file

```js
var database = firebase.database();

var leadsRef = database.ref('/Category/');
leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(childSnapshot);
    });
});
```

And in my browser console I'm seeing something like this.

[image]

Please help to retrieve `cat_names` value into html table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call "val()" on the snapshot:

```
var data = snapshot.val();
```

please note that using a foreach on that data won't work, since the result will not be an array

Comment: and how to display data to html table, please help i'm noob to javascript

Comment: document.write(data); shows only [object Object]. how to get cat_name inside unique keys?

Comment: use a for(var key in data) and access it with data[key]

Comment: sorry i know this is silly but can you give me code. i want to display all values of cat_name: _____ in my tabel